# How to use a voter inside the security file in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I created a special voter to check for a condition that allow or not users to access to a part of my website.

I succeeded to test my voter it inside a Controller this way and It's working.

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted(UserVoter::IF_USER_AGREED_CONDITIONS, $user);
```

In the `security.yml` file, there is a part allowed to control access to some pages depends on the roles of a use.

```
access_control:
- { path: ^/test, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
- { path: ^/test2, roles: IF_USER_AGREED_CONDITIONS }
```

When I tried to do the same using my special voter, the framework show me ervery time the error page *(Which is supposed to appear, if the user is not allowed on this page)*, whether the condition is satisfied or not.

The point is I don't want to modify all my controllers to add this line, because the `security.yml` file is called by default.

Comment: I don't know what conditions are (except for `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` that is a well-known) but I suspect that `access_control` route order is "buggy" as even for `test2` you'll finish everytime on the first rule.

Answer (score 0):

The access_control URLs are prefixes - so, in a usual instance they would be required for `/admin`, or `/admin/some-other-page`. So, the check for /test is being fired and checked but not /test2 - you can check the most specific paths first, and have /test2 listed first.

For the security voter, you don't need to specifically mention that in the access_control - it's listed, and so a security check will happen - in the code-block you have above the check is listed right there - 'is the role IF_USER_AGREED_CONDITIONS?'.  If its not explicitly listed, it will fall back to see what voters are supported, where the voters `$subject` will be an instance of a `Request`, in the same way you get one easily in a controller. The check of 'is this supported' is a) it's a `Request` and b) the `$subject->getUri();` starts '/test2'.

When both both those checks on the subject is true - then you can make the main check - did the user agree to the conditions.